# d3 v4 wrap text field (not axis)

Tags: d3.js

I have a pie with a legend and I need to wrap the legend but the spans overlap one another.
[My test pie](https://jsfiddle.net/jwaldner/r6fjsnv5/)

```
  // Apend only to the enter selection
    legendEnter.append("text")
         .text(function (d) {
             return d.data.label;

         })
         .style("font-size", 12)
         .attr("y", 10)
         .attr("x", 11)
         .call(wrap, 20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that `wrap()` function from Mike Bostock works, you have to set a `dy` attribute to the texts:

```
.text(function(d) {
        return d.data.label;

    })
    .style("font-size", 12)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", 0)//set the dy here
    .attr("x", 11)
    .call(wrap, 40);
```

Here is your update jsfiddle (I changed some values to give the texts more room): https://jsfiddle.net/5c0fn7gw/